# my rails 3 app needs to accept html data, and display it but safely! how to minimize security perils?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, http-post

One of the features of my app is to permit a user to add their facebook or twitter 'button' to their profile.

The 'obvious' approach is give them a text_area field, have them paste the facebook or twitter 'code', then on their profile display `raw fbk_button_field` and `raw twitter_button_field`

(Facebook is an iframe, twitter is a reference to remote ajax).

But obviously a user could paste anything into that field, and I'm assuming Thats A Pretty Bad Thing that leaves the system open to a variety of exploits.

So what is the right way to permit users to add 'social buttons' to their profile, without being able to insert an exploit instead.

Answer (score 0):

The most secure solution would be to have them enter their Twitter or Facebook account and recreate the button yourself. That way you can easily strip HTML from the account name and you don't have to worry.

While the above is ideal, you could also use something like the [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) gem to strip out HTML tags and attributes.

Comment: thanks. however we cant create the buttons for them (would require them to give us their credentials), and if we use sanitize to strip, it of course breaks the links.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you're talking about the http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton type of buttons, correct? You don't need credentials to create one of those. Sanitize can be whitelisted, you can tell it not to strip HTMl tags with "a" in them and "href" attribute.